# Difference between covariant derivative, gradient, Lie derivative, Lie bracket, Poisson bracket, Christoffel symbols. With examples and cases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have some knowledge but when I started to examine these notions I was confused. I have a sess in my mind. Do someone clear up the difference between covariant derivative, gradient, Lie derivative, Lie bracket, and Poisson bracket, Christoffel symbols. Please with the examples of some use. It is very hard for me to operate abstract formulae and fields without relations to real cases.

In my research work, I deal with the 3D nonorthogonal curvilinear coordinate systems for describing the motions of bodies and particles in the context of making nonlinear control lows and understanding this topic is highly important for me.

I understand the common meaning of covariant derivative and Christoffel symbols but I don't understand what these are useful for in real life. And why we need to introduce another differential operators like Lie and Poisson.

Comment: If you want to truly know what all of these mean and have some time on your hand, I can wholeheartedly recommend Frederic Schuller's course on the geometric anatomy of theoretical physics. It's on youtube and it's a masterpiece. (I know this is the opposite to a quick fix, but man, these lectures are gold)

Comment: @TBissinger, thanks a lot. But In my case, I try it. But it is a too long way with this course I see

Comment: @TBissinger, I found this course too time-consuming. Probably you could recommend some good books for me?

Comment: Totally understandable. On a similar level as the Schuller course, there is Marian Fecko's book on differential geometry for physicists. But that is a thick book, too, so I guess this isn't a much easier way to get into the material. Sorry for not being more of a help.